# Adding one more row to matrix doesn't change null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Why is that if a row is attached as the new last row of a matrix,then that matrix is going to have the same null space as before adding the row?

Null space deals with columns,how their combinations result in the zero vector.But,adding one more row means adding one more component to the previous vectors.

Why is null space preserved?Does it matter if that new row is linearly independent or not?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say the null space is preserved because you're in a different vector space. The null space in the original vector space might be preserved.

Comment: Adding a row at the bottom doesn't change the domain space, so it makes sense compare the two null spaces, and the new null space will be contained in the old one, since any vector killed by all $n+1$ rows will be killed by each of the first $n$ rows. But the new null space could be properly smaller -- for example, start with 2x3 matrix with rows $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, and add the row $(0,0,1)$. The new kernel is just $(0,0,0)$ while old one was $(0,0,z)$

Answer (score 1):

Where did you hear this? It’s clearly untrue: the null space of $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ is spanned by $(0,0,1)$, but the null space of the identity matrix consists only of the zero vector.

Also, the null space of a matrix doesn’t just have to do with its columns: it’s the orthogonal complement of the row space.